# Apply format arguments to struct members in Display implementation

Tags: rust

I want to apply format arguments (for example to limit the amount of digits) to the members of my struct. My current implementation looks roughly like this:

```rust
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Vec2 { x: f32, y: f32 }
impl fmt::Display for Vec2 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "[{}, {}]", self.x, self.y)
    }
}
```

If I use the automatically derived debug printing using e.g. `{:.2?}`, the arguments are applied and only 2 places after the decimal are printed. This doesn't seem to work with my `Display` implementation though using `{:.2}`. I tried to look at the Debug implementation using `cargo expand` but there are many functions specifically for `Debug`.

Comment: looks like working as expected: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dff31c4758213086c4131bec06db5f20

Comment: @Netwave If I understand the OP correctly, he want to specify the formatting specifiers when formatting _the container_, e.g. `println!("{:.2}", Vec2 { x: 1.111111, y: 0. });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to forward the formatting:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for Vec2 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("[")?;
        fmt::Display::fmt(&self.x, f)?;
        f.write_str(", ")?;
        fmt::Display::fmt(&self.y, f)?;
        f.write_str("]")
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to have all formatting specifiers, you have to implement additional traits. For floats, it's only [`std::fmt::LowerExp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/trait.LowerExp.html) and [`std::fmt::UpperExp`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fmt/trait.UpperExp.html). You can make a little helper function to not duplicate code:

```rust
impl Vec2 {
    fn fmt(
        &self,
        f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>,
        fmt_fn: fn(&f32, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result,
    ) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_str("[")?;
        fmt_fn(&self.x, f)?;
        f.write_str(", ")?;
        fmt_fn(&self.y, f)?;
        f.write_str("]")
    }
}
impl fmt::Display for Vec2 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.fmt(f, fmt::Display::fmt)
    }
}
impl fmt::LowerExp for Vec2 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.fmt(f, fmt::LowerExp::fmt)
    }
}
impl fmt::UpperExp for Vec2 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        self.fmt(f, fmt::UpperExp::fmt)
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good but I actually also want to use generics with the implementation so it's pretty annoying that multiple trait implementations are needed.

Comment: @LinusDikomey What's the problem if you use generics?